# Cannot connect to Azure Database for MySQL

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-database-mysql

I created an Azure Database for MySQL. When I try connect to it from MySQL Workbench, it cannot connect. However if I test the connection, the test passes.

When I test the connection, the test is successful:

[image]

When I try to connect however, it can't:

[image]

On the Azure Portal, I've allowed all IP addresses on the firewall and disabled "Enfore SSL connection":

[image]

Any ideas? The connection fails in less than 5 seconds, so I don't think it's a timeout issue. Here is a list of all the timeouts on MySQL Server (on Azure):

[image]

Comment: I'm using MySQL Workbech 8.0.16 and the MySQL Server version on Azure is 5.7

Comment: Try to check if this helps? try increasing timeout  value https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-lost-connection.html

Comment: Thanks Nancy. I can try that, however the error appears within 5 seconds or less of attempting the connection. So it's nowhere near the default of 30 seconds timeout that MySQL Server has? But I will check and let you know. Thanks again

Comment: I checked all the timeouts and they seem fine... I've added a screenshot to my original question showing all the timeouts...

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by changing the bind_address=0.0.0.0 (mariadb.cnf or mysql.cnf).

Now I can connect to it using telnet (to check the setting).